# How to use std::tuple types with boost::mpl algorithms?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, boost-mpl

The `boost::mpl` algorithms seem not to be able to work on `std::tuple` types out of the box, e.g., the following does not compile (boost-1.46.0, g++ snapshot 2011-02-19):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>

namespace mpl=boost::mpl;

typedef mpl::vector<int,float,bool> types;
static_assert(mpl::contains<types, float>::value, "vector contains bool");

typedef std::tuple<int,float,bool> types2;
// the following does not compile:
// error: no class template named ‘apply’ in ‘struct boost::mpl::contains_impl<boost::mpl::non_sequence_tag>’
static_assert(mpl::contains<types2, float>::value, "tuple contains bool");
```

**What is the easiest way to make the `boost::mpl` algorithms work on `std::tuple`?**

- Does evtl. `boost::fusion` provide this functionality (as it does so for `boost::tuple`)?
- If not, would it be possible to carry over the fusion implementation for `boost::tuple` to `std::tuple` easily?
- If not either, do I really have to implement [all the intrinsic metafunctions listed in the MPL documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/intrinsic-metafunctions.html) or which ones would be sufficient? (The docs only says "*many of intrinsic metafunctions offer a default implementation that will work in majority of cases*", but it is not clear which ones exactly. And some tests with just providing begin and end did not lead me anywhere).

Comment: The easiest answer I can suggest is to just use boost's.

Comment: But this would not be possible if you have existing code that returns `std::tuple`s or code that expects `std::tuple`s -- you would have to convert types in both directions which is somewhat awkward. I also thought that `boost::tuple` was something like an "early prototype" after which `std::tuple` later on was modeled, and thus that `std::tuple` would replace `boost::tuple` in the long run?

Comment: going to boost types is easy, it's going back that may be difficult...

Comment: See my updates. I have a full `to_boost` and `to_std` template that allows conversion to and from arbitrary boost mpl Sequences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting from std::tuple to boost types and back seems to be the easiest way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/not.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

template<typename Sequence, typename T>
struct push_front;

template<template<typename...> class Sequence, typename T, typename ... Args>
struct push_front< Sequence<Args...>,T> {
  typedef Sequence<T, Args...> type;
};

template<template<typename...> class To, typename From> struct tuple_change;

template<template<typename...> class To, template<typename...> class From, typename ... Args>
struct tuple_change<To, From<Args...>>
{
  typedef To<Args...> type;
};

template<typename Sequence, size_t N>
struct at : std::tuple_element<N,Sequence> { };

template<typename Sequence>
struct empty;

template<template<typename...> class Sequence, typename ... Args>
struct empty<Sequence<Args...>> {
  typedef Sequence<> type;
};

template<
  size_t N,
  typename Sequence,
  template<typename> class Pred,
  typename ... Args >
struct while_impl
{
  typedef typename mpl::if_c<
    Pred<
        typename at<Sequence, sizeof...(Args) - N -1>::type
    >::value,
    typename push_front<
        typename while_impl<N-1, Sequence, Pred, Args...>::type, 
            typename at<Sequence,sizeof...(Args)-N-1>::type
    >::type,
    typename empty< Sequence > ::type
  >::type type;
};

template<
  typename Sequence,
  template<typename> class Pred,
  typename ... Args >
struct while_impl<-1, Sequence, Pred, Args...>
: empty<Sequence> {
};


template<
  typename Sequence,
  template<typename> class Pred>
struct while_;

template<
  template<typename...> class Sequence,
  template<typename> class Pred,
  typename ... Args >
struct while_< Sequence<Args...>, Pred >
{
  typedef typename while_impl<sizeof...(Args)-1, Sequence<Args...>, Pred, Args...>::type type;
};

template<typename T>
struct not_na : mpl::not_< std::is_same<mpl_::na, T> >
{ };

template<template<typename...> class To, typename From>
struct to_boost;

template<template<typename...> class To, typename...Args >
struct to_boost<To, std::tuple<Args...> > :
  tuple_change< mpl::vector, std::tuple<Args...> >
{ };

template< typename From >
struct to_std;

template<template<typename...> class From, typename...Args >
struct to_std< From<Args...> > :
   while_<typename tuple_change< std::tuple, From<Args...> >::type, not_na>
{ };

static_assert(
std::is_same<
    mpl::vector< char, int, bool>,
    typename to_boost<mpl::vector, std::tuple<char, int, bool> >::type
  >::value,
"tuple_change to boost failed");

static_assert(
  std::is_same<
    std::tuple< char, int, bool>,
    typename to_std< mpl::vector<char, int, bool> >::type
  >::value,
"tuple_change from boost failed");

int main(){ return 0;}
```

*tested with:
 boost_1_46_0 and g++-4.5 on MacOSx
 boost_1_45_0 and g++-4.5 on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I am not able to compile your example. I correct at --> at_c, empty<...>::type--> empty<...>::value and added the missing includes, but still get errors. Could you evtl. have another look? -- For conversion I have another, shorter solution that I will post in a minute. Is there anything wrong with mine? -- Finally, I thought conversion is bad as it is not compile-time-efficient.

Comment: @Lars. I have no idea what happened. I guess I didn't get my whole test file. A new one is posted. It compiles as `g++-4.5 -std=c++0x test.cpp`

Comment: @Lars. I should probably also mention that I am working on re-working parts of boost.mpl to work with `std::tuple`s. I'll try to post some code online later but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around MPL::bind. I do know that the above code is different than what I am going to be posting (mainly `template<typename> class X` -> `typename X` with a child-template struct named apply, like boost does).

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Thanks a lot, the new version compiles fine. -- Should you find out how to avoid conversions, I would be very interested, because I did not manage to do so at all...

Comment: @Lars Specifically, what functionality do you need?

Comment: @KitsuneYMG I thought the "right" approach would be to make `std::tuple` a MPL sequence, so you can use it wherever you use say `mpl::vector`. But tried for a while and got it working to some extent, but it keeps throwing incomprehensible error messages at me, so I gave up and thought I would ask here if anybody knows about a solution.

Comment: @Lars the good news is that the to_boost struct has almost no overhead. Its literally two extra template instantiations. (to_boost and tuple_change). No recursion needed. The reverse is linear =/

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Thanks. You are right and I just should leave it here and use the conversion. Hopefully someone will update boost::mpl to work with `std::tuple` in the near future anyway.

Answer (score 9):

If you wanted to not convert the std::tuple into a mpl type, you can overload the tag dispatching boost mpl uses:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/mpl/sequence_tag.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pop_front_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_front_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/front_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/empty_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/back_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/clear_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pop_back_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/iterator_tags.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/next_prior.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/deref.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/begin_end_fwd.hpp>


namespace boost { namespace mpl {
  namespace aux { struct std_tuple; }

  template<class ... Args>
  struct sequence_tag<std::tuple<Args...> >
  {
    typedef aux::std_tuple type;
  };

  template<>
  struct front_impl< aux::std_tuple >
  {
    template< typename Tuple > struct apply
        : std::tuple_element<0, Tuple>
    {
    };
  };

  template<>
  struct empty_impl< aux::std_tuple >
  {
      template< typename Tuple > struct apply
          : std::integral_constant<bool, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value == 0>
      {
      };
  };

  template<>
  struct pop_front_impl< aux::std_tuple >
  {
    template< typename Tuple > struct apply;

    template< class First, class ... Types > struct apply<std::tuple<First, Types...>>
    {
      typedef std::tuple<Types...> type;
    };
  };

  template<>
  struct push_front_impl< aux::std_tuple >
  {
    template< typename Tuple, typename T > struct apply;

    template< typename T, typename ... Args >
    struct apply<std::tuple<Args...>, T>
    {
        typedef std::tuple<T, Args...> type;
    };
  };

  template<>
  struct push_back_impl< aux::std_tuple >
  {
    template< typename Tuple, typename T > struct apply;

    template< typename T, typename ... Args  >
    struct apply<std::tuple<Args...>, T>
    {
      typedef std::tuple<Args..., T> type;
    };
  };


  template<>
  struct size_impl< aux::std_tuple >
  {
    template< typename Tuple > struct apply
        : std::tuple_size<Tuple>
    {
    };
  };

  template<>
  struct at_impl< aux::std_tuple >
  {
    template< typename Tuple, typename N > struct apply
        : std::tuple_element<N::value, Tuple>
    {
    };
  };

  template<>
  struct back_impl< aux::std_tuple >
  {
    template< typename Tuple > struct apply
        : std::tuple_element<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1, Tuple>
    {
    };
  };

  template<>
  struct clear_impl< aux::std_tuple >
  {
    template< typename Tuple > struct apply
    {
      typedef std::tuple<> type;
    };
  };

  template<>
  struct pop_back_impl< aux::std_tuple >
  {
    template<int ...> struct tuple_seq {};
    template<int N, int ...S> struct tuple_gens : tuple_gens<N-1, N-1, S...> {};
    template<int ...S> struct tuple_gens<0, S...>{ typedef tuple_seq<S...> type; };

    template < class Tuple, class Index> struct apply_impl;
    template < class Tuple, int ... S> struct apply_impl<Tuple, tuple_seq<S...>>
    {
      typedef std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<S, Tuple>::type...> type;
    };

    template< typename Tuple > struct apply : apply_impl<Tuple, typename tuple_gens<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>::type> { };
  };

template< class ... Args >
struct tuple_iter;

  template< class ... Args >
  struct tuple_iter<std::tuple<Args...>>
  {
    typedef aux::std_tuple tag;
    typedef forward_iterator_tag category;
  };

template<>
struct begin_impl< aux::std_tuple >
{
  template< class Tuple > struct apply
  {
    typedef tuple_iter<Tuple> type;
  };
};

template<>
struct end_impl< aux::std_tuple >
{
  template< typename > struct apply
  {
    typedef tuple_iter<std::tuple<>> type;
  };
};

template< typename First, class ... Args >
struct deref< tuple_iter<std::tuple<First, Args...> > >
{
  typedef First type;
};

template< typename First, class ... Args >
struct next< tuple_iter<std::tuple<First, Args...>> >
{
  typedef tuple_iter< std::tuple<Args...> > type;
};

} }
```

And the associated test:

```
#include <boost/mpl/pop_front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/empty.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/clear.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pop_back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>


#include <boost/mpl/aux_/test.hpp>
MPL_TEST_CASE()
{
  typedef std::tuple<int, char, bool> Tuple;
  MPL_ASSERT((is_same<front<Tuple>::type, int>));
  MPL_ASSERT_RELATION( size<Tuple>::type::value, ==, 3 );
  MPL_ASSERT(( is_same< pop_front<Tuple>::type, std::tuple<char, bool> > ));
  MPL_ASSERT(( is_same< push_front<Tuple, unsigned>::type, std::tuple<unsigned, int, char, bool> > ));
  MPL_ASSERT(( is_same< push_back<Tuple, unsigned>::type, std::tuple<int, char, bool, unsigned> > ));
  MPL_ASSERT_RELATION( empty<Tuple>::type::value, ==, false );
  MPL_ASSERT(( is_same< at_c<Tuple, 0>::type, int > ));
  MPL_ASSERT(( is_same< at_c<Tuple, 1>::type, char > ));
  MPL_ASSERT(( is_same< back<Tuple>::type, bool > ));
  MPL_ASSERT(( is_same< clear<Tuple>::type, std::tuple<> > ));
  MPL_ASSERT(( is_same< pop_back<Tuple>::type, std::tuple<int, char> > ));
  MPL_ASSERT(( contains<Tuple, int> ));
  MPL_ASSERT(( contains<Tuple, char> ));
  MPL_ASSERT(( contains<Tuple, bool> ));
  MPL_ASSERT_NOT(( contains<Tuple, unsigned> ));

}
```

I tested this with gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.2.  It should contain everything you need to use anything in the mpl (actually a litte more than it needs).  You can think of a tuple as a mpl::list (forward iterator compile type).  So, to make it play nice you should implmenet what boost::mpl::list does. A quick look into the boost/mpl/list/aux_ directory:
begin_end.hpp  empty.hpp   iterator.hpp  pop_front.hpp  push_back.hpp   size.hpp
clear.hpp      front.hpp   push_front.hpp  tag.hpp
are the relevant files that need to be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

This is my version for converting between std::tuple and boost types, but as said in the comment above, conversion probably is not very compile-time efficient, i.e., will result in (unnecessary) long compile times. A solution that avoids conversion surely would be preferred...

```
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>

namespace mpl=boost::mpl;

//_ 1. vector_size and vector_at for std::tuple and mpl sequences
template <typename SEQ> struct vector_size 
: mpl::size<SEQ>
{};

template <typename... TYPES> struct vector_size<std::tuple<TYPES...>> 
: std::tuple_size<std::tuple<TYPES...>>
{};

template <typename SEQ, size_t N> struct vector_at 
: mpl::at_c<SEQ, N>
{};

template <typename... TYPES, size_t N> struct vector_at<std::tuple<TYPES...>, N> 
: std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<TYPES...>>
{};

//_ 2. convert
template <template <typename...> class COLLECT,
      typename SEQ, size_t N, typename... ARGS>
struct convert_helper 
  : convert_helper<COLLECT, SEQ, N-1, typename vector_at<SEQ, N-1>::type, ARGS...>
{};

template <template <typename...> class COLLECT, typename SEQ, typename... ARGS>
struct convert_helper<COLLECT, SEQ, 0, ARGS...> {
  typedef COLLECT<ARGS...> type;
};

template <template <typename...> class COLLECT, typename SEQ>
struct convert 
  : convert_helper<COLLECT, SEQ, vector_size<SEQ>::value>
{};

//_ 3. tests
typedef std::tuple<int, float, bool> types;
typedef mpl::vector<int, float, bool> types_v;

static_assert(std::is_same<convert<std::tuple, types_v>::type, types>::value, "boost2std works");
static_assert(std::is_same<convert<mpl::vector,types>::type, types_v>::value, "std2boost works");

int main() {}
```